# Pass a javascript variable from parent to the iframe

Tags: javascript

I know we can pass a javascript variable from an iframe to the parent frame like this:

If the parent and iframe were both on the same domain, we can call a function of the parent window:

iframe code:

```
window.postMe = "postMe value here";
window.parent.myFunction(postMe);
```

In the parent window, we can define a function like this:

```
function myFunction(postMe) {
    ((console&&console.log)||alert)("postMe= " + postMe);
}
```

And the code above logs the "postMe" value correctly.

But my question is how to modify **this code** in order to **pass "postMe" from parent to the iframe**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue using the `myFunction` on the parent, you can have the parent function accept a callback passed by the child:

```
window.postMe = "postMe value here";
window.parent.myFunction(postMe, (response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

```
function myFunction(postMe, callback) {
  const val = "postMe= " + postMe;

  // do something with val in parent:
  ((console&&console.log)||alert)(val);

  // do something with val in child:
  callback(val);
}
```

See here for a live demonstration (can't be embedded as a Stack Snippet due to sandboxing issues):

https://jsfiddle.net/kc24onbq/

For one-way communication from the parent to the child, access the `contentWindow` of the iframe from the parent:

```
// child
function childFn(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

```
// parent
iFrameElement.contentWindow.childFn('foo');
```

Comment: unfortunately, I can't make it work (The first code) would you please explain it further?

Comment: The first part is the code that is supposed to be on the iframe code and the second one should be on the parent, right?

Comment: Wait ... I want to pass postMe from parent to iframe right? So I need the postMe as a variable inside the parent code... not in the iframe code... correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: You were asking how to modify your existing code, which had `postMe` in the iframe, and was sending the information to the parent, which is what I copied. You're free to send anything back to the child, see the `const val` line - whatever you put there will be sent to the iframe

Comment: Thank you... your code works great... Now I'm going to post another question on my issue...

Comment: Can you please have a look at this discussion here:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456068/how-can-i-call-the-function-of-iframe-from-parent