# How can I call the function of iframe from parent?

Tags: javascript, iframe, articulate-storyline

If the parent and iframe were both on the same domain, we can call a function of the parent window from iframe:

iframe code:

```
// here we call 'myFunction' which is a parent function

window.postMe = "postMe value here";
window.parent.myFunction(postMe);
```

In the parent window, we can define a function like this:

```
function myFunction(postMe) {
    ((console&&console.log)||alert)("postMe= " + postMe);
}
```

And the code above logs the "postMe" value correctly.

But my question is how can I call the function of iframe from parent.

To be more clear I want this code on my iframe:

```
 function myFunction(postMe) {
        ((console&&console.log)||alert)("postMe= " + postMe);
    }
```

then I want to be able to call `myFunction(postMe);` on the parent ...

Note: I can't select the iframe like `HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow` or `window.frames['name']` for some reasons.

The final goal is: I want to pass a variable multiple times and every time I want from parent to the iframe.  @CertainPerformance has a solution for this that I can't make it work.

iframe code:

```
window.postMeToParent= "post me to parent";
window.parent.myFunction(postMeToParent, (response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

parent code:

```
function myFunction(postMeToParent, callback) {
  const postMeToiframe= "post me to iframe";

  // do something with postMeToiframe in parent:
  ((console&&console.log)||alert)(postMeToParent);

  // do something with postMeToiframe in child:
  callback(postMeToiframe);
}
```

The problem is it only can be run via iframe and I can't call the function and pass variables from parent.

Comment: _"Note: I can't select the iframe like HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow or window.frames['name'] for some reasons."_  What reasons?  Those reasons may well prevent any other sensible solution.

Comment: I'm using Articulate Storyline and that causes the problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the function object from iframe to parent function and invoke from there.

On the parent:

```
function tunnel(fn){
     fn('postMe');
}
```

On the iframe:

```
function myFunction(postMe) {
     ((console&&console.log)||alert)("postMe= " + postMe);
}
window.parent.tunnel(myFunction);
```

If your parent document will not be loaded at that point, try using below

```
var parentDocument = window.parent.document; 
$( parentDocument ).ready(function() { 
     window.parent.tunnel(myFunction); 
}
```

Comment: But there is a problem that is really confusing me: I want to call myFunction (the iFrame function) with user click.  Here I get TypeError: window.parent.tunnel is not a function because the iframe is loaded but the parent side code was not executed

Comment: If your parent document will not be loaded at that point, try using below
`
var parentDocument = window.parent.document;
$( parentDocument ).ready(function() {
     window.parent.tunnel(myFunction);
}
`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.tunnel is not a function

Comment: parent code is executed whenever user clicks... I think that causes the problem...